# Tastypie Single Resource

Tags: django, api, tastypie

I am writing an API with tastypie and I would like an API endpoint to only return 1 instance of a resource. The way I would like this to work is to enforce a parameter such as an ID.

For example, I would like /api/v1/users to return an error or a statement that says a required parameter is not there. However, I would like /api/v1/user/:id to simple return the id of that User.

Maybe I'm not searching up the right thing but I can't find any documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following within your Class Meta

```
    list_allowed_methods = []
    detail_allowed_methods = ['get']
```

This will disable listing values but allow them when an id is supplied.